# Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 (I know what does it mean)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure that uses this code in MYSQL:

```
DECLARE id_historico_adscripciones_personal int;

SET @id_historico_adscripciones_personal = (select max(id) from historico_adscripciones_personal)+1;

INSERT INTO historico_adscripciones_personal(id,id_empleado,id_estatus_historico,id_estatus,id_rme_o_dep,sueldo,moneda,observaciones,fecha_creacion,fecha_actualizacion values(@id_historico_adscripciones_personal,@id_empleado_o,@id_estatus_historico_o,5,@id_rme_o_dep,@sueldo_o,@moneda_o,@observaciones_o,now(),now());
```

I get the following error from MYSQL:

```
Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

I know what that means, the topic here is that if  in the code above I change after the word values @id_historico_adscripciones_personal by a number (i.e: 71)

```
 INSERT INTO historico_adscripciones_personal(id,id_empleado,id_estatus_historico,id_estatus,id_rme_o_dep,sueldo,moneda,observaciones,fecha_creacion,fecha_actualizacion) values(71,@id_empleado_o,@id_estatus_historico_o,5,@id_rme_o_dep,@sueldo_o,@moneda_o,@observaciones_o,now(),now());
```

I dont get the error message. I've already tested the `SET` procedure and everything seems to be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forgot close a parenthesis in the INSERT.

```
INSERT INTO historico_adscripciones_persona (
    id,
    id_empleado,
    id_estatus_historico,
    id_estatus,
    id_rme_o_dep,
    sueldo,
    moneda,
    observaciones,
    fecha_creacion,
--  fecha_actualizacion  <-- ")"
    fecha_actualizacion)
VALUES (
    @id_historico_adscripciones_personal,
    @id_empleado_o,
    @id_estatus_historico_o,
    5,
    @id_rme_o_dep,
    @sueldo_o,
    @moneda_o,
    @observaciones_o,
    now(),
    now()
);
```

A couple of notes:

- `@id_historico_adscripciones_personal` is a [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) and `id_historico_adscripciones_personal` one [13.6.4.1. Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html), are different variables.
- For the next `id` of your tables avoid using MAX. Try using [3.6.9 Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: Thank you very much @wchiquito , I think there is a MySQL bug because I already had the parenthesis closed and I although I checked the variables issue. What I did was replacing the way I generated the next `ID` of my tables using [3.6.9 Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html) and the problem got solved.