# Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 (MYSql)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Well, this error shows up and i'm not sure why, if someone could help me i would appreciate it. Here's the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `base`.`crearPublicacion` (IN exposicion INT, IN vendedorx INT, IN productox INT, IN categoria INT, IN tipo VARCHAR(45), IN precio INT)

BEGIN

DECLARE ide INT;

INSERT INTO publicacion VALUES (NULL, NULL, exposicion, vendedorx, productox, categoria, 1);

if tipo = "subasta" THEN

SELECT id 
INTO ide
FROM publicacion
WHERE vendedor = vendedorx
AND producto = productox;

insert into subasta values (ide, precio, vendedorx);

end if;

END
```

And when i call the procedure i use this:

```
call crearPublicacion(4, 3, 4, 1, "venta", 9700);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Code: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1) inside sp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185217/error-code-1136-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1-inside-sp)

Comment: Duplicate of all these SO questions; [#3185217](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185217), [#16340072](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340072),[#23051202](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051202),[#31689695](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689695)

Comment: @DaveAnderson i've seen them but my code has none of those problems.

Comment: What is the structure of your two tables where you do the insert? Unless you are explicitly declaring which columns you insert you must provided a value for all columns.[MySQL INSERT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)